# google analytics query time of last event

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm working on a portal website for the company I work at. It's just a website with links to the different applications/docs. The links are being tracked in Google Analytics. I can run a query to get the top ten most visited links. I also have a list of links that haven't been visited in the past 60 days (by running a query for links that were accessed in the last 60 days and looping through all the links in back-end code, comparing them). There was a suggestion to add a date/time for when those links were last clicked. Is this possible? The query below is close, but the same link can show up more than once with different dates.

```
ids=ga:123456789
dimensions=ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel,ga:date
*metrics=ga:totalEvents
*start-date=2014-11-29
*end-date=2015-01-29
```

Expected Results

```
ga:eventAction  ga:eventLabel   ga:date     ga:totalEvents 
2015 Enrollment Guide   hrlinks11   01-15-2015  1
ClaimsApp   claimslinks1    01-15-2015  1
CS Files    cslinks1    01-22-2015  1
Department Reports  adlinks1    01-15-2015  1
Frontend Site   cslinks2    01-26-2015  2
Application Utilities   islinks2    01-28-2015  1
Cell Phone Forms    oslinks5    01-23-2015  1
Code of Ethics  hrlinks2    01-29-2015  1
```

Actual Results

```
ga:eventAction  ga:eventLabel   ga:date     ga:totalEvents 
2015 Enrollment Guide   hrlinks11   01-15-2015  1
ClaimsApp   claimslinks1    01-15-2015  1
CS Files    cslinks1    01-20-2015  1
CS Files    cslinks1    01-21-2015  1
CS Files    cslinks1    01-22-2015  1
Department Reports  adlinks1    01-15-2015  1
Frontend Site   cslinks2    01-22-2015  2
Frontend Site   cslinks2    01-23-2015  2
Frontend Site   cslinks2    01-24-2015  2
Frontend Site   cslinks2    01-26-2015  2
Application Utilities   islinks2    01-19-2015  1
Application Utilities   islinks2    01-22-2015  1
Application Utilities   islinks2    01-23-2015  1
Application Utilities   islinks2    01-27-2015  4
Application Utilities   islinks2    01-28-2015  1
Cell Phone Forms    oslinks5    01-23-2015  1
Code of Ethics  hrlinks2    01-29-2015  1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to find links that *weren't* click within the last 60 days, you don't need to use the `ga:date` dimension, as `start-date` and `end-date` will give you all you need.

If you already have a list of all possible links (from you question text it sounds like you do), then all you have to do is query for all links clicked within the past 60 days, and filter those out of the full set of links. What remains will be links that haven't been visited within the past 60 days.

Query:

```
ids=ga:123456789
metrics=ga:totalEvents
dimensions=ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel
start-date=60daysAgo
end-date=today
```

Code (pseudo-code):

```
// Assuming you have an array of all possible links.
var = allLinks [...];

// Obtained from the query above.
var = visitedLinks = [...];

var = unvisitedLinks = allLinks.filter(function(link) {
  return visitedLinks.contains(link.eventLabel);
});
```

Comment: I am doing exactly that. My goal is on the displayed unvisited links to display the date they were last accessed/clicked. That's why I had the ga:date dimension.

Comment: In that case, use `ga:date` and set a sort value of `sort=ga:date`. That way, as you're looping through the results, the last result in the list for a particular label will always be the most recent occurrence of that event.